# Borrar archivo de una carpeta en Archivos de programa

Tags: java, netbeans

tengo un pequeño codigo para borrar un archivo de una carpeta, funciona en carpetas de usuario, pero en las carpetas de administrador, como en C: Archivos de programa, no funciona el borrar archivos, hay alguna forma o codigo con el cual se pueda borrar?

```
File archive = new File ("C:\\Program Files\\ICOMM\\DE_ICOMMBackbone\\ICOMM\\WAS\\Inbound\\TriggerIPS-I.txt");
        if (archive.exists()){
            System.out.println("Archive in the Inbound folder");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Waiting Trigger from IPS-I");
            while ((archive.exists()) != true ){}
        }
```

Comment: Para borrar dentro de archivos de programa y otras ubicaciones del sistema, tu proceso debe ejecutarse _elevado_. El código es el mismo, pero el usuario debe ejecutarlo con privilegios de administrador, pues las carpetas son de acceso restringido.

Answer (score 0):

Para borra el archivo puedes usar el método `delete()`, de hecho puedes agregarlo a tu código al verificar que el archivo existe, si es así, procedes a eliminarlo:

```
File archive = new File ("C:\\Program Files\\ICOMM\\DE_ICOMMBackbone\\ICOMM\\WAS\\Inbound\\TriggerIPS-I.txt");
        if (archive.exists()){
            System.out.println("Archive in the Inbound folder");

            //Elimina archivo
            archive.delete();

        }else {
            System.out.println("Waiting Trigger from IPS-I");
            while ((archive.exists()) != true ){}
        }
```

Es importante comentar que para eliminar el archivo, el usuario que ejecute la aplicación debe tener permisos de administrador para realizar esta acción.

Answer (score -1):

Ejecuta tu programa con permisos de administrador. Si estás corriendo desde windows abre una consola de comandos (CMD) como admin. Y desde ahí ejecuta tu programa (.class) con el comando java

Comment: Podrias mirar [answer]? tu respuesta se reporto como de baja calidad, porque parece mas un comentario que una respuesta